# UnitTest GRPC file upload using bloomRPC

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to implement the gRPC file upload service, where i will accept bytes as input.

But want to know how can i test it using bloomRPC. I can test normal JSON gRPC services but dont see any option to test file upload / stream services in the same.

**Want to know if there any way to test it from boomRPC/other tool and not using java client.**

Comment: BloomRPC seems to support client streaming (bidi streaming as well) as per https://github.com/bloomrpc/bloomrpc#features . I think you can use that.

Comment: Any example on streaming, bcz when i try to run it starts and keeps running, Any idea how do i send next messages (stream messages[multiple]) using bloomrpc ?